# "Unexpected indentation" with restructuredtext list

Tags: html-lists, restructuredtext

I did not succeed to get a simple 3 levels indented list with Restructuredtext:

```
$ cat test.rst 
Title
======

- aaaa
  - aaaa2
  - aaaa2
      - aaaa3
- aaaa
- aaaa

Ok

$ rst2html test.rst > /tmp/a.html
test.rst:7: (ERROR/3) Unexpected indentation.
$
```

I've try different combination of spaces in front of `aaaa3` but I get in all cases `(ERROR/3) Unexpected indentation.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Nested lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html?highlight=nested%20lists#lists-and-quote-like-blocks) are tricky because different levels require blank lines between those levels.

> Nested lists are possible, but be aware that they must be separated from the parent list items by blank lines

This should work:

```
- aaaa

  - aaaa2
  - aaaa2

    - aaaa3

- aaaa
- aaaa
```